# pyspark streaming app to calculate moving average

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming

My data stream contains a timestamp and a value corresponding to it,

```
3-10-14 1:06:05,9.74
3-10-14 1:08:02,10.44
3-10-14 1:09:20,9.83
3-10-14 1:11:53,10.49
```

I need to take a moving average of 10 elements. I have been exploring foreachRDD option with functions but no success after going through spark documentation but couldn't find any clear pointers.

Comment: When you say "data stream" does this mean the data is coming in one at a a time? Or do you have access to the current as well as previous timestamp/values?

Comment: it is being read from a file, via filestream over a directory

Answer (score 0):

Say your data is in a list `D` of tuples `(time,value)`. The moving average over 10 elements (independent of timestamp) is this, using the numpy command mean():

```
import numpy as np

def mov_avg(D):

    avg_list = []
    Dval = [item[1] for item in D] #extracts the values from D, ignoring time stamp
    L = len(D)

    for i in range(L):
        if i<10:
            l = Dval[:i+1]
            M = np.mean(l)
            avg_list.append(M)

        else:
            l = Dval[i-9:i+1]
            M = np.mean(l)
            avg_list.append(M)

    return avg_list
```

This function will return a list `avg_list` such that `avg_list[j]` is the average of the 10 values of your data `D` before and including the `j+1`th value. So if we set `A = mov_avg(D)` then `A[12]` will be the average of values 3 through 12 (this is 10 elements if we include 3 and 12) of `D`, while `A[6]` will be the average of values 0 through 6 of `D`.

There may be a pre-existing command for this, but this is how you would code it otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Casey, I need to implement it in terms of spark streaming. Your solution does not use any streaming data structures.